# Прокрутка страницы вверх

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, что бы кнопка прокрутки вверх появлялась после того как страница прокрутится вниз примерно на 2000 px, или появлялась на 2 или 3 экране.

Вот код:

```
$(function(){
  $.fn.scrollToTop=function(){
    $(this).hide().removeAttr("href");
    if($(window).scrollTop()!="0"){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  var scrollDiv=$(this);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()=="0"){
    $(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")
    }else{
    $(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  });
    $(this).click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow")
    })
  }
});
$(function() {$("#toTop").scrollToTop();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот нужный кусок кода.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('.elem').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.elem').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Мне бы лучше увидеть код в конечном виде. Так что бы я смог полностью скопировать и вставить. 
Я совсем не разбираюсь в js.

Comment: > [Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием: форум не является фриланс-биржей.](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8)